# How to understand the use of "which" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> There was clearly nothing to do but sit down and cry. So Della cried. **Which led to the thought that life is made up of little cries and smiles, with more little cries than smiles**.

source:[A Special Story for Christmas: 'The Gift of the Magi'](http://learningenglish.voanews.com/content/a-23-2005-12-22-voa2-83125392/124554.html)

I just can't understand the meaning of the bold sentence above, and I can't convince myself to accept that sentence as clarified —— especially the use of "which"! For there is nothing to choose from!

What's more, it's not a question sentence(without question mark)!

Why don't use "what",which seems much more natural and clarified to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be punctuated so:

So Della cried -- which led to the thought that ...

which = her crying

The antecedent of *which* is implicit there rather than explicit.

Answer (score 2):

It is, technically, not a sentence (as traditional grammarbooks use that term<sup>†</sup>) but a subordinate clause, separated from its head clause by a period to coerce a 'pause' in your reading. (Real Writers write for the ear, not for the eye—and certainly not for grammar teachers.)

Specifically, it is a relative clause headed by *which*, whose referent is the previous sentence, *Della cried*. You may paraphrase:

> So Della cried—and that led to the thought ...

---

<sub><sup>†</sup>It may surprise you to know that many modern grammars do not use the term *sentence* at all. *Sentence* is probably best reserved for analysis of written texts, where it means "whatever stretch of words lies between two full stops", those being periods, question marks, and exclamation marks.</sub>

Comment: Very useful and valuable explanation. Thank you very much.